# $\{\omega|f_n(\omega)>0$ for infinitely many $n\}$ is a measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Assume $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of measurable functions on some measure space. Prove that $$\{\omega|f_n(\omega)>0 \text{ for infinitely many } n\}$$ is a measurable set. Show that the set is also measurable when "infinitely" is replaced by "finitely".

$\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n>m}\{\omega|f_n(\omega)>0\}$ Since the sequence is measurable, the result follows; when replaced by "finitely" we have $\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{n>m}\{\omega|f_n(\omega)\leq 0\}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: No, it is not. The first expression you wrote does not depend on $m $, and it is simply the set of $\omega $ such that some $f_n (\omega)>0$ for some $n $.

Comment: The second expression you wrote is the set of $\omega $ such that for all but finitely many $n $, $f_n (\omega)>0$. This is not what you want either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first the inner union should be over e.g. $n\geq m$

and in the second it is better if you consider $\{\omega | f_n(w)\leq 0\}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if they are complementary.

Comment: yes, now it is  correct

Comment: It looks like the OP changed to $\leq$ as well..